# How to integrate twitter into iphone application using oauth

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

I have integrated PlainOauth from the source 
http://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth
in my application.

It is not working for me. it is giving the message

Status posted. HTTP result code: 401

When posting the posts to the twitter.

Do any one have faced this problem before. can any one suggest me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all. I did the mistake in twitter application registration.

I checked 'read ' insted of ' read and write '  when i register my app.

thank you all